# Binding return null

Tags: android, android-intent, data-binding

I want to bind this:

```
filter= (boolean) intent.getSerializableExtra(FILTER);
```

Sometimes the intent return null. I wanna set filter to false if the intent returns NULL or set the value of the intent if not

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

```
if((intent.getSerializableExtra(FILTER)) == null)
        filter= false;
    else
        filter= intent != null && (boolean) intent.getSerializableExtra(FILTER);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use `getSerializableExtra()` for `boolean` at all. Use `getBooleanExtra()` instead.

```
filter = intent.getBooleanExtra(FILTER, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filter= intent != null && (boolean) intent.getSerializableExtra(FILTER);
```

This will short circuit to false if intent is null.